# Bootstrap responsiveness issue with unread notification badge on bell icon

Tags: css, layout, bootstrap-4, responsive-design, responsiveness

I have a blue circle/badge which appears if there are any unread notifications which looks fine on a normal size screen when the screen is fully maximized.

[image]

I have this HTML:

```html
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link position-relative" href="#">
        <i class="fas fa-bell notification"></i>
    @if (loggedInUserHasUnreadNotifications())
        <div class="unread-notifications-circle-nav"></div>
    @endif
    </a>
</li>
```

This is the CSS:

```css
.unread-notifications-circle-nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 16px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #007bff;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

However the image loses its position when the screen size if reduced. I have tried ages to get the image to be position where it should be positioned but I cannot get it to work. How do I fix this so that the blue circle is always where it should be?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By using a media query you can switch the position.

1. First you need to know at which breakpoint the navigation layout is changed (768px I believe).
2. Second, it's best to take a mobile first approach => media query min-width and not max-width
3. The position can switch from left to right if you set `left: auto;`

   ```
   /* mobile first */  
   .unread-notifications-circle-nav {
       position: absolute;
       top: 10px;
       left: auto;
       width: 10px;
       height: 10px;
       background: #007bff;
       border-radius: 50%;
   }

   /* MD breakpoint and up */  
   @media only screen and (min-width: 768px){
       .unread-notifications-circle-nav {
           left: 16px;
       }
   }
   ```

Using consistent media queries with `min-width` keeps your code cleaner in the long run.
You can reverse the process by using `max-width` but it has some issues (1px gap for ex.).

Untested code but this should work.